# Install php5.6-gd on ubuntu 14.04 but php is not recognizing it

Tags: php, ubuntu, php-gd

I have php version 5.6.22. Install php5.6-gd on ubuntu 14.04 but php is not recognizing it. 
I have installed php5.6-gd by following below steps.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5.6-gd
```

Added 
`extension=gd.so` in php.ini file.

But still it is not recognizing gd library.
And out put of below command is :

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep php
dh-php5                                         install
libapache2-mod-php5                             install
php-common                                      install
php-pear                                        install
php5-cli                                        install
php5-common                                     install
php5-curl                                       install
php5-dev                                        install
php5-json                                       install
php5-mcrypt                                     install
php5-mysql                                      install
php5-readline                                   install
php5.6-common                                   install
php5.6-gd                                       install
pkg-php-tools                                   install
```

Comment: What error are you getting in your code? Have you restarted all services (apache2, php-fpm if using it, etc) after doing the install?

Comment: I have restarted apache couple of time, on phpinfo i am not able to see GD lib related thing. So i am not doing any kind of code.

Answer (score 0):

Restart `apache2` and `php`.

Also, create a page with just `phpinfo();` and see if gd.so is being loaded. Check the php.ini path as well and make sure this is the same INI file you modified.